# Specify A WORK DAY in iCalendar file for office outlook

Tags: outlook, ms-office, icalendar

I was trying to make an iCalendar file for all platform, one event in the file is a recurrence pattern which specifies the 9th work day every month, like the following content:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Test//Calendar//EN
X-PUBLISHED-TTL:PT1H
X-WR-CALNAME:TestCalendar
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:Test
DTSTART:20160101
DURATION:PT1D
RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR;BYSETPOS=9
SUMMARY:The 9th work day.
DESCRIPTION:This is the 9th day.
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

This event works fine both on iOS calendar and google calendar, but not work on Outlook calendar.

I've found this [link](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-outlook/outlook-ics-support/ac743e10-0191-4fe9-9ada-50ad3ca159ec?auth=1) which says that outlook calendar only supports BYSETPOS between -1 to 4, sadly this is almost being confirmed by my own experiment.

So I wonder if anyone has the same problem when importing your iCalendar file to Outlook, or is there any workaround to solve the BYSETPOS issue?

Answer (score 0):

I made a workaround yesterday.

Since my iCalendar file is being created by a RESTFul call hosted by .NET Web Api, and I have different kinds of RRULE to generate, in order to keep this case in the same design, I choose to generate this RRULE according to  *DateTime.Now*  and re-generate it for every call:

```
    private int GetTheWorkDay(int parameterX)
        => this.GetDaysInMonth()
            .Where(d => d.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday &&
                   d.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday)
            .OrderBy(d => d)
            .ToArray()[parameterX - 1]
            .Day

    public string ParseSetting(int parameterX)
        => $"FREQ=MONTHLY;BYMONTHDAY={this.GetTheWorkDay(parameterX)}";
```